# Aggregation issue with 2 collections

Tags: node.js, mongoose

**The purpose of this is to fetch A pro of Type Secretaire from a Cabinet with a specified name (in this case "Clinique Toto") and I'm struggling here.**

**Cab Model:**

```
var cabinet = new cabModel({
_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
InfoCab:{Nom: "Clinique Toto"} //This is the Name of the Cabinet
}); 

cabinet.save((err, cabinet) => {
```

**Pro Model**

```
var pro1 = new proModel({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    Nom: 'ProTITI',
    Cv:{ Fonction: { Secretaire: false}}
});

pro1.Cabinets.push(cabinet._id);
pro1.save((err, cabinet) =>  { });

var pro2 = new proModel({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    Nom: 'Pro_TOT',
    Cv:{ Fonction: { Secretaire: true}}
});
```

**Setting Secretaire: true for some of the Pros.**

```
pro2.Cabinets.push(cabinet._id);
pro2.save((err, cabinet) =>  { });

var pro3 = new proModel({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    Nom: 'Josianne',
    Cv:{ Fonction: { Secretaire: true}}
});
pro3.Cabinets.push(cabinet._id);
pro3.save((err, cabinet) =>  { });
```

**Pushing Pros created into the Cab.**

```
cabinet.Pro.push(pro1, pro2, pro3);
cabinet.save();

console.log("Done");
});

const handleError = function (err) {
console.error(err);
};
```

**I got to this so far:**

```
db.Pro.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        Cv: {
            Fonction: {
                Secretaire: true
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: "Cab",
         localField:"Nom",
         foreignField: "_id",
          as: "PK"
    }
}
])
```

**Here are the Schemas:**
Pro Schema:

```
const ProSchema = new Schema({
_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
 Cv: {Fonction: {Pro: {type: Boolean,},
                 Secretaire: {type: Boolean}
    }
}
```

**CabSchema:**

```
const CabSchema = new Schema({
Pro: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ProSchema' }],
InfoCab: {
        Nom: {type: String}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add Schema for your models so your question has more clarification.

From the given information, it looks like Nom is a string, i.e. `Nom: 'Josianne'` and you are using lookup as follows:

```
$lookup:
{
    from: "Cab",
    localField:"Nom",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "PK"
}
```

1. Now the problem is `_id` is of type `ObjectId()`, which is a hash string uniquely generated, where `Nom` is a string created by you, logically they will never match.
2. iF `Cab` collection is same as `cabModel`, the foreignField should be `InfoCab.Nom`. i.e. `foreignField: "InfoCab.Nom",`

=== UPDATE ===

Couple of observations you might wana consider:

1. you should use the aggregation as following: `proModel.aggregate([...])`
2. If you are already using `ref` in your mongoose schema, you can use [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/populate.html) method.

Comment: Did you try #2?

Comment: this is the output with infocab.nom : { "_id" : ObjectId("59d4b229585ee41a309ade51"), "Nom" : "Josianne", "Cv" : { "Fonction" : { "Secretaire" : true } }, "Cabinets" : [ ObjectId("59d4b229585ee41a309ade4e") ], "__v" : 0, "PK" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59d4b229585ee41a309ade50"), "Nom" : "Pro_TOT", "Cv" : { "Fonction" : { "Secretaire" : true } }, "Cabinets" : [ ObjectId("59d4b229585ee41a309ade4e") ], "__v" : 0, "PK" : [ ] }

The thing here is I'd like have the cab name as a filter too.

Cheers,

Comment: I found .populate to be quite useless since I can do it by pushing. Are you saying populate can be useful to fetch a pro with said type from a cab named Clinique toto ? cheers

Comment: In Aggregation framework you can add as many pipelines as you require. so after `$lookup` you can use `$match` again.
pipeline: $lookup, $match, $group, etc

Comment: if you have an attribute with type `ObjecId` and you have set its `ref` parameter correctly. In the populate function you just need to enter its reference, kindly check the documentation i have attached. you will understand